# How to navigate to file in WebStorm if file belongs to excluded folder?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've excluded vendor folder from indexing.

I can navigate to file if it outside of vendor folder with <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + N</kbd> but if a file inside the one WebStorm can't find it.

Comment: files excluded from indexing are not available in **Navigate | File**. But you can use quick search in the **Project** tool window to jump to it - just start typing its name there. Unfortunately quick search doesn't work of the containing folder is collapsed, so you have to expand your `vendor` folder to be able to jump to the file

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do an "All" search with <kbd>double shift</kbd>. It should appear there if you have ever visited the file. If you haven't opened the file, most probably it will not appear there.

The reason for excluding files from indexing is mainly the good performance and marking directories that contain for example build artifacts or libraries to not add noise to your search results. That's why you will not see them.